# pass json object to controller

Tags: jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I need your help. I have to send json object to spring mvc controller and get it back and replace it in  field in a view. My project is Spring MVC. It's new for me.I'm posting Controller and jQuery code.

[image]

```js
setOperator = function(newOperator) {

       // alert("operator  " + newOperator);
            if (newOperator == '=') {
               // alert("newOperator is = ");
                //AJAX, JSON
                json_result = {"jsn_result" : lastNumber};
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/calc",
                    data: JSON.stringify(json_result), // Note it is important
                    success :function(result) {
                        console.log(json_result.jsn_result);
                    }
                });
                equalsPressed = true;
                calculate();
                return;
            }

            if (!equalsPressed) {
               // alert("followed by an operator (+, -, *, /)");
                calculate();
            }

            equalsPressed = false;
            operator = newOperator;
            operatorSet = true;
            lastNumber = parseFloat(currNumberCtl.val());
              },
```

```js
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class CalculatorController {
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
  return "calculator";
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Please include the code as text in a `code` section.

Comment: what kind of changes I have to include in controller?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to do several
Let's suppose you want to pass to the controller a JSON like this:

```
{
  "name": "The name",
  "surname": "The surname"
}
```

And let's suppose you want back in the view a JSON like this:

```
{
  "passedFullName": "The name & The surname"
}
```

You have to:
create models for the input JSON and output JSON
create a method able in receiving the input JSON and manage it

I'd do the following:
Input model creation: i'd create a java class like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class InputJson implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9159921073367603471L;
private String name;
private String surname;
public String getName()
{
return name;
}
public void setName(String name)
{
this.name = name;
}
public String getSurname()
{
return surname;
}
public void setSurname(String surname)
{
this.surname = surname;
}

}
```

Then I'd create a class like this (for the output JSON):

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class OutputJson implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1504974498083180855L;
private String passedFullName;
public String getPassedFullName()
{
return passedFullName;
}
public void setPassedFullName(String passedFullName)
{
this.passedFullName = passedFullName;
}

}
```

Then in your controller I'd create a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST }, value = { "/calc" })
public ResponseEntity<OutputJson> handleJson(@RequestBody InputJson input) throws Exception
{
  OutputJson result = new OutputJson();
  result. setPassedFullName(input.getName()+" & "+input.getSurname());
  return new ResponseEntity<OutputJson>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Sure you can make more complicated Objects... these were just a simple sample
I hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

First, create a Java Object for your json data, it may help use a online generator: [JsonSchema2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org)
Then change your method declaretion:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.Post,consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody String printWelcome(@RequestBody YourObject model) {
    return "calculator";
}
```

So basically keep in mind the Http method(POST), the format which you accept data(json,xml or both), the `@RequestBody` for indicating the data must be recovered from the Http body, and `@ResponseBody` if your content must be a raw or serialized instead of invoking your view.